# Device not found. Arch Linux drops me into emergency shell

Tags: linux, boot, arch-linux

I tried to reboot my laptop and had the following message greet me :

```
Starting version 245.6-6-arch
ERROR: resume: hibernation device '/dev/mapper/arch-swap' not found
ERROR: device '/dev/mapper/arch-root' not found. Skipping fsck.
You are now being dropped into an emergency shell.
sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
[rootfs ]# _
```

I do not remember doing anything to my system prior to this, apart from normal usage.
I am now in this emergency shell. I have no idea what to do now. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I was able to chroot into my system and install the lts-kernel. This enabled me to boot  again. So it seems to be a kernel related issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug in the firmware of the nvme device which prevented the kernel from recognizing the hard drive during boot.

If you are having the some problem on a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon (Gen 6) update the firmware using [fwupd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fwupd) and the problem should disappear .

Answer (score 1):

This is because arch is not booting to the specified drive. It is searching for a drive in /dev/sda3

Try

```
mount /dev/sda2 new_root
exit
```

Comment: Is there a configuration file, where this is stored? I can still boot with the lts kernel.

Comment: once this works once, how do you set it permenently?